# MVC and Fluent Validation using a When

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

here is what I have..

```
public class PersonalDetailValidator : AbstractValidator<PersonalDetail>
{
    public PersonalDetailValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.LastName).NotNull().WithMessage("Person's Last Name is required");
        RuleFor(x => x.FirstName).NotEmpty().When(x => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.LastName) == false).WithMessage("Person's First Name is required");
    }
}

[Validator(typeof(PersonalDetailValidator))]
public class PersonalDetail
{

    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that the first rule, against the Last name is working on the client side but after entering something into the last name the rule against the first name is not firing.

Can anyone help?

Comment: `.When()` is not supported client side. (refer [documentation](https://fluentvalidation.net/aspnet) - see section titled _Clientside Validation_ for supported rules)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FluentValidation will work with ASP.NET MVC’s client-side validation, but not all rules are supported. For example, any rules defined using a condition (with `When/Unless`), custom validators, or calls to `Must` will not run on the client side.

See more info [here](https://fluentvalidation.net/aspnet)

Comment: In this case I would consider to use some client side validation

Answer (score 0):

Fluent Validation supports server-side validations. You can use a few validations on client-side (like required).

If you want to use server-side validations on client-side, you need an another library for that. You can use all server-side validations on the client-side. Check Form Helper library on github. It can help you to transfer server-side validations to client-side.